# How can I do the same thing over and over every 1-4 seconds in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to run a script every few seconds (4 or less) in google app engine to process user input and generate output. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Run a cron job.</strike>

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html

> A cron job will invoke a URL at a
>   given time of day. A URL invoked by
>   cron is subject to the same limits and
>   quotas as a normal HTTP request,
>   including the request time limit.
>   .

Also consider the Task Queue - http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html

Comment: I can only run cron jobs at most once every minute, though, and I need to run them every 1-4 seconds.

Comment: Hmmm - yes.  Perhaps the use Task Queue? You could chain tasks by adding a new task at the completion of the previous one.

Comment: If you use task queues, make sure you set up your queue to be served at a fast enough rate (e.g., 15/m for one every four seconds).   This is an average rate, so you might not get a task executed exactly every 4 seconds - so whether this will work depends on how sensitive you are to this.  Beware that this is going to use up a lot of the task queue quota - 1/sec is 86.4k of the 100k daily quota.

Also consider triggering the script via an external cronjob.  This makes the interval quite dependable & saves your task quota at the cost of an external dependency (the machine running your cronjob).

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider what you're doing. As Ash Kim says, you can do it with the task queue, but first take a close look if you really need to run a process like this. Is it possible to rewrite things so the task runs only when needed, or immediately, or lazily (that is, only when the results are needed)?