# How to best run function every x seconds on Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using Google App Engine Python 2.7 I want to create job that checks every 10-60s whether heart-beat events where received from all clients. If not an (email) alert is triggered.

The basic alternatives I can imagine are:

- Google Task Queue
- Google Deferred Task Queue
- Cron Jobs (minimum of 1min, but maybe I could just set up a couple of them?)
- (seems not recommended: using sleep)

I found this question but was hoping for a more precise answer:
[how-can-i-do-the-same-thing-over-and-over-every-1-4-seconds-in-google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986648/how-can-i-do-the-same-thing-over-and-over-every-1-4-seconds-in-google-app-engine)

The reason I want to check that frequently is that an alert needs to be triggered if no update is received for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a cron job that runs every minute. Then in the cron job, do your heartbeat check, sleep for a while, check again, sleep ...

Comment: I might as well just test this, I just read somewhere that the sleep counts towards the quota which makes it seem stupid to waste that on a wai.t

Comment: Yes, I believe it does count toward the quota.